# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96 using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to open my default chrome browser for over 1 month now. I have not succeeded in now. I have made 2 other posts which were not of much help. So therefore I just try one last time and hope for the best.

What I'm trying is that I would like to open my main chrome browser with selenium.
The reason I want to do this is to use certain cookies with a login from my main browser.
The only way I could just see myself getting it was to open my chrome browser which I use daily.

Have been working on some code for a while now and would still like to be able to use it in my main browser.

My code looks like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\rober\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\rober\Desktop\Bot\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.zalando.dk/jordan-air-jordan-1-mid-sneakers-high-joc12n001-a18.html")

buyButton = False

while buyButton is False:

    try:
        
        addToCartBtn = addButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/x-wrapper-re-1-6/div/div[4]/button')

        print("Varen er udsolgt")

        time.sleep(1)
        driver.refresh()

    except:
        addToCartBtn = addButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="picker-trigger"]')

        print("Varen er på Lager")
        buyButton = True

while buyButton is True:
    time.sleep(1)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.uc-btn#uc-btn-accept-banner"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Vælg størrelse']"))).click()
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'size-picker')]//span[text()='51.5']"))))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'size-picker')]//span[text()='51.5']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Læg i indkøbskurv']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Indkøbskurv"]'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".z-coast-base__totals-tile .z-1-button__content"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Registrér dig"]'))).click()
```

My error look like this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 99.0.4844.82 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 99.0.4844.82 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=99.0*
- But you are using *chromedriver=96.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=96.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 96

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=96.0* and the *chrome=99.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v99.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.51/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=99.0* (as per [chromedriver=98.0.4758.48 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/98.0.4758.48/notes.txt)).

Comment: Now I see what he meant by his "normal chrome driver". Seems like he never created a session before, so he doesn't want to start it in his normal chrome. His original title was confusing

Comment: Hey, Undetected Selenium.

The answer to this, has helped a lot on this mistake I have. And has actually also fixed the bug.

But it still does not open my main browser which I would like to use, with the right cookies.
But I think that is not relevant to this question, and will therefore make a new question when I can now again.

Thanks for the help

// Robert